# Force download file from plugin (change output http headers)

Tags: plugin-development

I'm developing a plugin and I want to add a menu entry that forces a file download (a CSV).

There are a few posts in this forum and over the internet with a similar solution, all of them are quite old and that solution seems not to work anymore.

This is my current approach (based on the mentioned posts). This does force a file download, but the file is actually a generated HTML with all WP admin menu and everything.

`MyPlugin::__construct()`

```
$capability = 'manage_options';
$menu_slug  = 'myplugin-data-export';
$function   = [$this, 'exportCSVdata'];
add_submenu_page(null, '', '', $capability, $menu_slug, $function);
```

`MyPlugin::exportCSVdata()`

```
public function exportCSVdata()
{
    header("Content-type: application/x-msdownload");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    echo 'data';
    exit();
}
```

This function is executed when I enter the URL *http://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=myplugin-data-export*

So, the question maybe is,

how can I create a function inside my plugin class that generates a naked page? With no header, includes and all the WP html stuff?

In some ohter posts I saw a proposal to use `admin-post.php` instead of `admin.php` but didn't work either.

**EDIT**
Plugin is being run as follows:

```
if ( !class_exists( 'MyPlugin' ) ) {
    class MyPlugin
    {
        static $instance = false;

        public static function getInstance()
        {
            if ( !self::$instance )
                self::$instance = new self;
            return self::$instance;
        }

        public function __construct()
        {
            register_activation_hook( __FILE__, [$this, 'mypluginInstall']);
            add_action('admin_menu', [$this, 'adminMenuEntries']);
        }

        public function adminMenuEntries()
        {
            //... some stuff
            $capability = 'manage_options';
            $menu_slug  = 'myplugin-data-export';
            $function   = [$this, 'exportCSVdata'];
            add_submenu_page(null, '', '', $capability, $menu_slug, $function);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you see [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/102452/73)? That is still working fine.

Comment: That's the one I mentioned with `admin-post.php`, it serves a blank page with no error message or log. I'll try to elaborate if you say it should work.

Comment: How s MyPlugin being constructed and ran? When/where?

Comment: @TomJNowell I added some code to original post

Comment: @fuxia after testing more carefully again that link returns a blank page... doesn't work

Comment: @user761076 you share the class definition, but you didn't share how it's used or created, defining a class doesn't do anything on its own, at a minimum I would expect to see `getInstance()` being called. You also didn't share where this code is located. It's not clear if this is inside aa theme, if it's been nested inside another function, if it's in the top level of a plugin file, etc

Comment: @TomJNowell this is the top level plugin page, that's all the relevant stuff. The problem with `admin_post` was I was calling `add_action` in a wrong order, see my comments on selected answer.

Comment: @user761076 there is no `new MyPlugin()` or `MyPlugin::getInstance()`, the code in your question is defining a class, but it never uses or creates objects with it. If I copy pasted it into a plugin locally it would do nothing, you did not share how your code runs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can I create a function inside my plugin class that generates a
> naked page? With no header, includes and all the WP html stuff?

There are many ways to do that, e.g. by using the [`admin_post` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_post/) just as you could see in [@fuxia's answer here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/102452/73) (which does work in WordPress 5.8.1 for what you're trying to do), or the [`parse_request` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/parse_request/) as you could see in [my answer here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/395811) (for outputting an image data) — the WordPress REST API also uses the same hook.

But you said:

> I'm developing a plugin and I want to add a menu entry that forces a
> file download (a CSV).

So if it has to be using a standard admin page URL like `http://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=myplugin-data-export`, then you could hook your `exportCSVdata()` function on the [`load-<page hook>` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/load-page_hook/), where in your case, the `<page hook>` value would be the hook name as returned by [`add_submenu_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/):

```php
$hook = add_submenu_page('<parent slug>, '', '<menu title>', $capability, $menu_slug, $function);
add_action( "load-$hook", [ $this, 'exportCSVdata' ] );
```

Then clicking the menu item would force the file download and the (CSV) file would also have a valid data (and no admin menu HTML displayed on the page).

But then, you could actually link the menu to `http://example.com/wp-admin/admin-post.php?action=print.csv` by passing an empty string (`''`) as the 6th parameter for `add_submenu_page()`, **and** set the menu slug to `admin-post.php?action=print.csv`:

```php
add_submenu_page('<parent slug>, '', '<menu title>', $capability, 'admin-post.php?action=print.csv', '');
```

That way, I bet the `admin_post` hook would work as expected.

So for example, in your class constructor, you would add `add_action( 'admin_post_print.csv', [ $this, 'exportCSVdata' ] );`.

Comment: Perfect, the problem was I was calling `add_action( 'admin_post_print.csv', [ $this, 'exportCSVdata' ] );` in the wrong place. It's working now on the plugin `__construct` function, but it was failing after all the `add_submenu()` calls.

Comment: About if it's a menu entry or a button inside a plugin page it doesn't matter, to make it simpler I added the link in a button inside a plugin page.

Comment: "it was failing after all the `add_submenu()` calls" - the `admin_post` hook runs in a standalone PHP file, namely `admin-post.php`, and the `admin_menu` hook is not fired on that page, because it's not an admin page with UIs like the admin menu, and instead, it's an endpoint in the admin side which one can use to process form submissions or deliver a custom content like the one in question.